# Why is the subview's draw method not called in this case?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview

I have a number of cases where a subview's draw method is/ is not called and I don't understand why. I provide one example.

My understanding is that when a view is initialised with a frame its draw method is called - but this is not always the case. As you can see in the code I have then tried to trigger a call to draw in the super view's viewDidLoad, but this has no effect either.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let testView = TestView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let horizontalConstraint = testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint])
        //      self.testView.setNeedsDisplay(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        //      self.testView.setNeedsDisplay(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        //      self.testView.updateLayer()
        self.testView.needsDisplay = true
        print("test view did load...")
        print("controller view frame and bounds: ", self.view.frame, self.view.bounds)
        print("child frame and bounds: ", self.testView.frame, self.testView.bounds)
    }
}

class TestView: NSView {
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        print("subview draw method called...")
        NSColor.white.set()
        self.bounds.frame()
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add two more constraints, a height constant of 200 and a width constant of 200. Like `testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)` and `testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)`?

Comment: @GustavoConde thanks that works for this case, although I still don't get why draw is not called in the code I posted given that a width and height were passed into the subview initialiser

Comment: The width and height are translated into constraints if `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `true`. What is the size of the child view without constraints?

Comment: As Willeke said, if you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` then the frame that you set when initializing the view has no effect as you expect to size the view with autolayout constraints. Then because you are only setting the position the view gets width and height = 0. Then why would draw gets called if there is nothing to draw as the view has no size.